# pyenv initialization in .bash_profile vs. .bashrc (after release 2.0.0)

Tags: bash, documentation, pyenv

With the recent release of pyenv 2.0.0, the [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) currently recommends the following configuration for a bash shell:

```
# inside ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

# inside ~/.bashrc
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

If I'm not allowed to edit .bashrc on my system (for reasons completely unrelated to pyenv), what would be the drawbacks of just putting both inside my profile, like this:

```
# inside ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

I've been using it like this for a few hours, and I haven't noticed any issues (on MacOS, with a Homebrew installation of pyenv, and Python 3.6/3.7/3.8 virtual environments created with venv). I'm trying to understand what might be the drawbacks of configuring my system this way, and why the documentation makes such a big deal about using both .bash_profile and .bashrc.

Will configuring pyenv in this way cause problems for me in the future?

Answer (score 0):

[Bash only runs `~/.bash_profile` when you start a login shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). When you start a new shell by typing `bash` or `exec bash`, its runs only `~/.bashrc`. However, you can work around this easily by always starting new shells with `bash -l` or `exec bash -l`, which will make the new shell a login shell.

To find out whether it makes a difference whether you don't run `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in non-login shells, let's have a look at what `pyenv init -` really does:

```sh
$ pyenv init - 
export PYENV_SHELL=bash
source '/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/2.0.0/libexec/../completions/pyenv.bash'
command pyenv rehash 2>/dev/null
pyenv() {
  local command
  command="${1:-}"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")"
    ;;
  *)
    command pyenv "$command" "$@"
    ;;
  esac
}
```

Since `export PYENV_SHELL=bash` puts `$PYENV_SHELL` into the environment, it will get imported for your non-login shells, too. So, that doesn't make any difference.

As for the rest, it looks like the main thing you're missing out on is command line completion for `pyenv`. Other than that, there's just some special wrapping for `pyenv shell` and `pyenv rehash`.

So, as long as you don't use tab completion for `pyenv` nor use the commands `pyenv shell` and `pyenv rehash` in your non-login shells, then it should make no difference. But even if you do want to use those there, you can simply start the shell with `bash -l` or just run `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` manually.